# Vue split components from a single .js file in multiple files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have created a component inside my `index.js` (where my main Vue code is). Now I would like to modularize the project and put the component into a separate file. I don't know how to do that because if I create e.g. `optionalapm.js` the main `index.js` returns an error that it can't locate the vue component `optionalapm` which I included.

How can I import the component into the `index.js`?

Here's my code of the component:

```
var optionalapm=Vue.component('optionalapm', {
props:['value'],
template:   `<div class="col-l-12 col-m-12 col-s-12 col-xs-emphased" style="background-color: #f9f9f9"">
                <p class="hidden-xl hidden-l hidden-m"></p>
                <p class="hidden-xl hidden-l hidden-m"></p> 
                <h3 style="text-align: center">APM</h3>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <div class="col-l-4">
                    <p style="text-align: center">Number of nodes</p>
                    <div class="form-input-set">
                        <select v-bind:value='value' v-on:input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)" v-on:change="$emit('calcapmprice')" class="form-select" style="background: white">
                            <option value="apmnodes0">
                                <p style="text-align: center">0</p>
                            </option>                                            
                            <option value="apmnodes1">
                                <p style="text-align: center">1</p>
                            </option>
                            <option value="apmnodes2">
                                <p style="text-align: center">2</p>
                            </option>
                            <option value="apmnodes3">
                                <p style="text-align: center">3</p>
                            </option>  
                        </select>
                    </div> 
                </div>
              </div>`,       
})
```

And that's the relevant code in the `index.js`:

```
var ececontent = new Vue({
    el:'#ece-content',
    data: {
        ...
    },
    methods: {
        ...
    },
    components: {
        optionalapm: optionalapm,
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Single File Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html), as described in the documentation. Next to it, read this [useful blog post](https://travishorn.com/getting-started-with-vue-single-file-components-f29765a771a3) about using SFC's.

Answer (score 0):

May be this wil be useful https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html

And you can use js modules https://javascript.info/modules-intro if you want modularize the project

Comment: Thanks for the links. As I understand from the vuejs guide it's not possible to just copy and paste the vue.component to another file right? It would be nice if I just could create a new file and include it in the index.JS file.

Comment: For this you need js modules. You can do it other way: put components into separate files, register it globally and include files in you page with script tag. But its not *good* way. I advise learn js modules. It is really useful for modularity